Exposing Nginx ingress controller services using Ngrok get Request Rejected
I am deploying an nginx ingress controller on a vm and using ngrok to expose it to public network but keep getting Request Rejected error after my master node ip changed. Is this error related to tls? or is it ip related?
Here is my ingress file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: lets-encrypt
    appprotect.f5.com/app-protect-policy: test-web/cafe-ingress
    appprotect.f5.com/app-protect-enable: "true"
spec:
  tls:
   - hosts:
       -  becoming-pika-enormously.ngrok-free.app
     secretName: test-ingress-tls-x7h51
  rules:
   - host: becoming-pika-enormously.ngrok-free.app
     http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tea-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: coffee-svc
            port:
              number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx

my nginx-ingress
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-ingress-67b4f9ff6-9cd8x   1/1     Running   0          5d8h
pod/nginx-ingress-67b4f9ff6-dphsr   1/1     Running   0          5d8h

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                         PORT(S)                      AGE
service/nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.152.183.70   172.16.2.0,172.16.2.108,172.16.2.109,172.16.1.145   80:30663/TCP,443:32022/TCP   5d8h

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-ingress   2/2     2            2           5d8h

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-67b4f9ff6   2         2         2       5d8h

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE    CONTAINERS      IMAGES                                           SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-67b4f9ff6   2         2         2       5d8h   nginx-ingress   docker.io/phunguyen1211/nginx-ic-nap-dos:3.6.1   app=nginx-ingress,pod-template-hash=67b4f9ff6

I change host to others like test.example and the curl work normally.

Have you taken a look at ngrok's ingress controller? https://ngrok.com/docs/k8s/getting-started-kic/
That way you can utilize ngrok's TLS Termination directly: https://ngrok.com/docs/http/tls-termination/#overview

@stmcallister After checking for a while, I have figure out that there is nothing wrong with the ingress controller or ngrok, it's just that the domain was blocked by the firewall. Now the issue is the tls, I am keep getting 301 error because of the certificate.
